# Drupal 8 missing data when changing content

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

On drupal 8, I created a template as suggested by debug. My code looks like this:

```
{% for key, element in elements if key|first != '#' %}
    {# element.content.field_shortcut_image #}
        <a href="{{ element.content.field_shortcut_url.0['#context'].value }}" class="col-sm-12 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths" >
            <div class="shortcut-bg" style="background: transparent url({{ file_url(element.content.field_shortcut_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}) no-repeat center center;"></div>
            <div class="shortcut-title">
                {% if element.content.field_shortcut_icon.0['#item'].entity.uri.value %}
                    <img src="{{ file_url(element.content.field_shortcut_icon.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}" class="shortcut-icon" alt="{{ element['#configuration'].label }} icon" >
                {% endif %}
                {{ element['#configuration'].label }}
            </div>
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, everytime i make any changes on drupal, like maybe update a content, that is not even related to that block, the data disappears. It looks like this when the data is present: 
http://prntscr.com/d2wmku

and looks like this after changing or adding any content:
http://prntscr.com/d2wmxu

The data comes back though when i clear cache in admin/config/development/performance, but it is a pain, since each time you create/edit a content it disappears. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: you can setup a cron every minute, but i don't know if this is the best way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for those noobs like me, maybe this will help.

Instead of getting the data from the #elements, i tried to use 'content' array, and that solved the issue for me. The data does not disappear on the content array when updating any content. my code looks like this:

```
{% set sicon = content.field_shortcut_icon.0['#item'].entity.uri.value %}
{% set sbg = content.field_shortcut_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value %}
{% set slink = content.field_shortcut_url.0['#context'].value %}
```